# При открытии PAS неактивны кнопки запуска в Delphi 7

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, ide

Я создал проект на Delphi 7. Сохранил, открываю его заново - это `*.pas` - не активны кнопки запуска и ctrl+f9, как устранить этот баг?

Проект без сохранения компилировался, после сохранения такая фигня. Раньше я с этим встречался через раз, теперь мне это надоело и я хочу справить раз и навсегда.

Comment: сохраняли/загружали правмльно? такое бывает, если загружать не проект, а его файлы

Comment: Да,видимо вы открыли только юнит. А надо было открыть проект,как сказали выше. попробуйте File->Open Project-> Ваш проект(Зайдите в папку, где сохранили, Дельфи увидеть проект с расширением .dpr)

Comment: Да конечно,  я  пробовал сохранить по другому , проект открываеться.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Проект на Delphi состоит из нескольких файлов:

***.pas** исходный код

***.dpr** файл проекта

***.dfm** файл формы

***.res** файл ресурсов

***.dcu** скомпилированый файл исходного кода

Любой файл откроется **IDE** но для того чтобы был открыт проект то открывать нужно ***.dpr**

Comment: Мне кажется, что *dcu* здесь лишнее

Comment: Почему лишнее?
Это все составляющие проекта,есть проекты и без **DFM**,есть проекты с **DCU** но без **PAS** , есть проекты с **PAS** но без **DCU**

Comment: Я сохранил Unit1.dfm и Unit1.pas . Открываю pas , отсуцтвует компиляция проекта

Comment: Тебе нужно создать новый проект и заменить и изменить соответствующие исходники.

Comment: В то йже папке есть ***.DPR** вот его и открывайте. и сохранять нужкно как **Save as Project**